# Do I still need to add verifications if the site has been verified through Google Analytics?

Tags: 7

I'm working my way through the items in the SEO Checklist module.  One of them is the Site Verification module. We have already verified our domain name through a Google Analytics account.  Do I still need to add a verification using the Site Verification module, or is it redundant at this point?

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you, of course. from the module's page:

> This module is useful for the following search engine verifications:
>
> - Google Webmaster Tools
> - Google Apps
> - Bing Webmaster Central (formerly Live Search)
> - Yahoo! Site Explorer
> - Yandex.ru
> - Any search engine or web service that uses META tags or file upload to verify that you are the owner of a site.

You are the one to know if you will need or want assistance with verification against above tools.